# ESP-32 won't communicate at all

Tags: debugging, esp32

I'm trying to program an ESP32-WROOM-32 on my own PCB. I'm an amateur.

[I asked a related question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/75864/can-you-program-an-esp32-with-an-arduino?noredirect=1#comment166099_75864) about how to program an ESP32 using an Arduino a few days ago. I've been experimenting with it and no matter what I try I always get "Timed out waiting for packet header".

I hook everything up like the @jurag suggested in my other question. [It's the same process you use](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/harshmangukiya/how-to-program-esp8266-with-arduino-uno-efb05f) for an ESP-8266. I've tried many different combinations (EN disconnected, EN connected to 3V3, EN connected to ground, IO0 connected to 3V3, etc). To be clear though I followed the instructions in that article by default.

- 3V3 -> 3V3
- GND -> GND
- IO0 -> GND
- EN -> 3V3
- TX -> TX
- RX -> RX

I checked my connections by hooking up 3V3 to RX, TX, IO0, and EN and checking the voltage on the ESP32 itself. It's good. The 3V makes it to the ESP32. The only one of note is EN. I've carefully inspected my board and soldering and there are no bridges yet when I give EN 3V I see 3V show up on some of the other pins. I am guessing it's supposed to do that.

What I am saying is I think I have it wired right. Also, I have a USB microscope and I don't see any bridges anywhere when I do a visual inspection. To make sure I could get it to work I tried a few things:

```
SUCCESS - programmed an ESP-8266 using the same technique

SUCCESS - programmed an ESP-32 dev board using the same technique

FAILURE - hot glued a spare ESP32-WROOM-32 to a spare PCB of the same design
```

I'm not sure what the next step I should take is. It never works when I try it with my PCB using the ESP32-WROOM-32 that I solder (or hot glue) on. If I open the serial console there is nothing (it doesn't print wifi networks).

I do have pins 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, and 25 hooked up to different things but none of them are doing anything.

I've spent 5 hours trying various combinations. I'm pretty sure I even hooked 3V3 and GND up backwards at some point. ...The LEDs on the board still light up but idk, maybe I fried the ESP32. In any case I probably tried each scenario 5 times before I made that particular mistake.

[image]

Comment: Usually TX is connected to RX and vice-versa... Are you sure you want TX connected to TX on both sides?

Comment: Apparently when you hook reset up to ground on an Arduino it just passes TX and RX through. But yep of course I tried that quite a few times.

Comment: You'll need to show a schematic of the board

Comment: Fair request about the schematic. I'd do it but making it presentable/understandable will be too much work (3-4) hours. ....I guess I'll test what I can with an ESP32 dev board by touching jumpers to the vias and correct a few mistakes I made and I'll bet the next board will come out right. Some good lessons learned. Just a real bummer because I wanted to see it work. ...this was a test board anyways.